# How to implement session using nodeJS TCP server with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a TCP based game server for iOS, it involves registration and login.
Users will be stored as a collection in MongoDB.
when login is done, I generate a unique session id - **How** ?

I wanted to know what all data remains with node server and what can be stored in db.
data like session tokens, or collection of sockets if I am maintaining a persistent connection etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.JS does not have any sessions by default. In fact, there is a [plug-in for managing sessions with MongoDB](https://github.com/mikkel/express-session-mongo).

It's not clear that you really need sessions however. If you're opening a direct socket with socket.io, that is a defacto session.

Comment: I was thinking, in case I go for HTTP based communication, I will need some sort of user tracking,
If I am using sockets, then its not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js itself does not manage sessions for you. It simply exposes an API to underlying unix facilities for Socket communication. HTTP in it self is a stateless protocol and does not have sessions either. SSH on the other hand is a stateful protocol, but I do not think either one would be good for you.

Creating a uniuqe ID is really simple, all you need to do is hash some data about the user. Their `SHA(IP address + time + username)`. See: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

One approach a lot of applications take is to create their own protocol and send messages using that. You will have to handle a lot of cases with that. And I myself have never dealt with mobile where you have serious connectivity challenges and caching requirements that are not a big problem on desktops.

To solve these problem, founder of Scribd started a company called Parse which should make it much easier for your to do things. Have a look at their website: https://parse.com/.

If you want to do some authentication however, have a look at Everyauth, it provides a lot of that for you. You can find it here: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/.